# Using a windows based program on Ubuntu called Groupmail 5?

Tags: installation

I just started using Ubuntu and am very happy with the system.I had a windows based program called Groupmail 5 that I used for marketing for my business.I talked to their IT people and they told me that it is windows based and that I would need a windows enabler to be able to use it on Linux,mhat is a good

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run it under Wine. Install Wine from the Softwarecenter. Afterwards right click on your setup.exe file and select "install with wine" or something like that.

For better performance, if it doesn't work well: In the Wine preferences menu you can select which Windows version you want to simulate. There is also a software called "winetricks", with it you can install missing .dll files, fonts etc. 
For further help you should consult the Wiki.

http://wiki.winehq.org/FrontPage

There is also a page where you can browse programs and their functionality under wine. Groupware wasn't listed, which means, that nobody has tested it.

http://appdb.winehq.org/index.php

If it doesn't work try virtualbox. Install it from the Softwarecenter, than install your windows inside and install your program inside windows. You can use it as a program window in Ubuntu. Try it, it is surprising.

Well, and there are some Alternatives. Best one would be, as there isn't a native alternative, to work with Thunderbird Add-Ons. Open Thunderbird - Tools - Addons to search for thousands of addons. Mail merge Addon for example enables thunderbird to send the same mail to thousands of directions. Use it with caution! Other addons improve Address books.

Answer (score 0):

Groupware may have problems running under Wine.  See [Wine forums](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=18928&sid=aa70855542654e39c6070f70c4c7acbd).  I would recommend that you run it in a virtual machine, using something like VirtualBox.  Its available in Ubuntu Apps.

To install, just click [**VirtualBox** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox-qt/)